# How to calculate the half-life of a hypothetical element in C using the rand() function

Tags: c

I need to estimate the half-life (in minutes) of an element with a decay constant lambda = 0.079 (min)^-1 using a C program that uses the rand() function for this. The purpose of this activity is to use computation to solve simple stochastic problems - hence the mandatory use of the rand() function.

My code for this is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define lambda  0.079       // Decay constant
#define N0      1000        // Number of unstable nuclei in t=0
#define dt      1e-6        // Time interval

main()
{
    double N = N0;   // Number of nuclei
    double t = 0;       // Time counter
    int i;

    while ( N > N0 / 2 ) {
        N = N - ( rand() % 1000 + 1 ) * lambda * dt;
        t = t + dt;
    }

    printf( "The half-life is %.3f", t );
}
```

Although the code in the image seems right to me, the result it provides is wrong. Instead of the half-life giving 8.77 minutes, as the theoretical formula - which is ln(2)/lambda -, it is giving 12.71 minutes. I can't understand where I'm going wrong!

Oh, and I must use the rand() function despite of all its problems

Comment: **WARNING**: Using [`rand()` is not ideal](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and you’re strongly encouraged to use an appropriate [random number generator facility in the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that produces high-quality random values. Using `time(NULL)` as a random number will produce identical results if run in the same second, and on many platforms `rand()` is *barely* random at all.

Comment: Side note: Watch this: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/goingnative-2013/rand-considered-harmful)

Comment: I'm not sure you're computing this correctly. I'd expect something like for any given element in an array there's a 1 in *N* chance that it will decay in any given timestep. As such, you iterate through all non-decayed elements repeatedly and observe the resultant count of decayed/non-decayed.

Comment: It has nothing to do with rand(). The average number decaying in small time dt is N.lambda.dt whereas your current code gives an average decay in that time of about 500.lambda.dt. In other words, while N>500 you are underestimating the decays and hence overestimating the half life.

Comment: You should use the Poisson distribution. Look into how that's used for radioactive decay and how you can change the output of rand into such a distribution.

Comment: @tadman Can you better formulate your last answer about iterations? Did not quite understand

Comment: I'm just suggesting you model this instead of just bash around with a handful of numbers.

Comment: @tadman Hm ok. I'm still a beginner, so I don't know how to do it properly, but thanks

Comment: @JOSE MEDEIROS DA COSTA NETTO If you want to use rand() then (a) you should seed it and (b) you need to change the decay line to ```N = N - 2*(rand()%(int)(N+1)) * lambda * dt;``` (or one or two similar alternatives) to get the right average decay rate. For more exactitude use a Binomial distribution with n=N (an integer) and p=lambda.dt, or, to a very good approximation, a Poisson distribution with mean N.lambda.dt (note that both of these change as N changes).

Comment: @lastchance Great! I have one question: why I have to multiply the `(rand()%int(N+1))*lambda*dt` by 2? There are a mathematical ou physical reason for this?

Comment: @JOSE MEDEIROS DA COSTA NETTO, the AVERAGE of 0,1,2,...,N is (N/2), but you need an average of N here. Physically, each of N particles has a probability lambda.dt of decaying in that time.

Comment: @lastchance, sorry, but I still don't get it. For me, `(rand()%int(N+1))` should draw a certain number of particles from my sample and `lambda*dt` should be their probability of decaying in a time dt. The 2 factor does not seems to make sense to me, despite it generates a pretty good approximation to the real value of the half-life

Comment: @JOSE MEDEIROS DA COSTA NETTO, if you apply (rand()%int(N+1)) then you will get the numbers from 0,1,2,...,N with (roughly) equal probability, bar the minor deficiencies of rand(). The average of these numbers is N/2. What you actually require is something with an average of N. So you can either change the modulo operation to (rand()%int(2*N+1)), so making the possible numbers go up to 2N or you can just multiply by 2. Take your pick! At the end of the day you are replacing a very skew probability distribution (binomial or Poisson) with a uniform one and you have to get the correct mean.

Comment: For me your code gives 12.647. BTW you forgot to initialize rand seed with `srand()`.

Answer (score 1):

You were using an incorrect random distribution for the number of nuclei that decayed each cycle.  I think you're looking for something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

// Decay over 1 minute = 0.079
// Decay over 1 second = 1-(1-0.079)^(1/60) = 0.00137
// Estimated half life = ln(2)/0.00137 = 505 seconds
#define LAMBDA 0.00137

#define INITIAL_COUNT 1000000

int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));

  unsigned int count = INITIAL_COUNT;
  unsigned int cycles = 0;
  unsigned int decay_count;

  printf("Nuclei: ");
  while (count >= INITIAL_COUNT / 2) {
    // Iterate over each nucleus and randomly decide if it decays.
    decay_count = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      decay_count += rand() < LAMBDA * RAND_MAX;
    }
    count -= decay_count;
    cycles++;
  }
  printf("\n");

  double half_life = cycles -
    (double)(INITIAL_COUNT / 2 - (int)count) / decay_count;

  printf("Half-life in seconds: %f\n", half_life);
  printf("Half-life in minutes: %f\n", half_life / 60);
}
```

Typical output:

```
Half-life in seconds: 505.214619
Half-life in minutes: 8.420244
```

This code calls `rand` many times in a very wasteful way, and will take a few seconds to run.  Not recommended for serious work.

Comment: Almost! I really want the half-life (in minutes, so lambda is in min^-1) of the element, not the number of cycles.

Comment: Can't you just edit the string in my final printf statement to say `minutes` instead of `us`?  If you're just waiting for trivial edits like that I think you should accept the answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Either way, your output is wrong! The half-life is given by ln(2)/lambda, so its value for this example is 8.77 minutes, not 9 minutes.

Comment: OK, I did three things to make it more accurate: calculate the fractional number of cycles where the decay to half occurred, use a smaller time step (with a correspondingly smaller lambda value), and increase the initial nuclei count to 1e6.  Note that 8.77 is not accurate either, probably because the lambda value of 0.079 was too large.  It's more like 8.41.